# How to create table postgresql Heroku?

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, heroku

I have database postgresql in Heroku and i have local app. My entity is "Product".
When i wanna open my application in spring boot i get ERROR: relation "product" does not exist.

I dont have any idea how create new table "product" in postgresql.
In mysql everythink is good

Comment: Are you using ddl-auto or some migration tool like liquibase?

Answer (score 0):

You can with do it manually by running `heroku pg:psql` and then running the appropriate SQL statements. Or you can use a migration framework in your app.

For more information on [running database migrations see the Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/running-database-migrations-for-java-apps).